# `rms::ols()`: how to fit a model without intercept

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I'd like to use the `ols()` (ordinary least squares) function from the `rms` package to do a multivariate linear regression, but I would not like it to calculate the intercept. Using `lm()` the syntax would be like:

```
model <- lm(formula = z ~ 0 + x + y, data = myData)
```

where the `0` stops it from calculating an intercept, and only two coefficients are returned, on for `x` and the other for `y`. How do I do this when using `ols()`? 
Trying

```
model <- ols(formula = z ~ 0 + x + y, data = myData)
```

did not work, it still returns an intercept and a coefficient each for `x` and `y`.

[Here is a link to a csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jp0oxl4p1ahzaag/ccd.csv)

It has five columns. For this example, can only use the first three columns:

```
model <- ols(formula = CorrEn ~ intEn_anti_ncp + intEn_par_ncp, data = ccd)
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try ols(formula = z ~ -1 + x + y, data = myData)

Comment: @droopy That made no difference whatsoever...what was your idea?

Comment: Can you give us a small, reproducible example to try this out?

Comment: It's a real pity there's no answer to this. I'm asking the same question right now

Answer (score 2):

`rms::ols` uses `rms:::Design` instead of `model.frame.default`. `Design` is called with the default of `intercept = 1`, so there is no (obvious) way to specify that there is no intercept. I assume there is a good reason for this, but you can try changing `ols` using `trace`.